# Extracting only the values that get used in the object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was just playing with a jBox.js a plugin that can be used for creating modals , tooltips and also gallries , its about a 1600+ lines of code , now i want to used the tooltip functionality ONLY. I know tooltips can be created using css only and also i know in JS this can be done with only a few couple of lines of JS, buts a custom requirement that i extract the code from this library only, I.E. i need to extract only the code that related to the tooltip , i managed to do that , I used the chrome dev tool and console.logs inside each function to see which are the functions that are executing and so i kept only those functions. I managed to reduce the lines of code from 1600+ to 900+ great.

**ISSUE:** Now the problem is , this is a huge and multipurpose plugin, it has a huge set of default values in its object literal(every plugin uses a object literal with default values) , see below:

```
this.options = {

        // jBox ID
        id: null,                   // Choose a unique id, otherwise jBox will set one for you (jBoxID1, jBoxID2, ...)

        // Dimensions
        width: 'auto',              // Width of content area (e.g. 'auto', 100)
        height: 'auto',             // Height of content area
        minWidth: null,             // Minimum width
        maxHeight: null,            // Minimum height
        minWidth: null,             // Maximum width
        maxHeight: null,            // Minimum height

        // Attach
        attach: null,               // Attach jBox to elements (if no target element is provided, jBox will use the attached element as target)
        trigger: 'click',           // The event to open or close your jBoxes, use 'click' or 'mouseenter'
        preventDefault: false,      // Prevent default event when opening jBox (e.g. don't follow the href in a link when clicking on it)

        // Content
        title: null,                // Adds a title to your jBox
        content: null,              // You can use a string to set text or HTML as content, or an element selector (e.g. jQuery('#jBox-content')) to append one or several elements (elements appended will get style display: 'block', so hide them with CSS style display: 'none' beforehand)
        getTitle: null,             // Get the title from an attribute when jBox opens
        getContent: null,           // Get the content from an attribute when jBox opens
        isolateScroll: true,        // Isolates scrolling to content container

        // Position
        target: null,               // The target element where jBox will be opened
        position: {
            x: 'center',            // Horizontal Position (Use a number, 'left', 'right' or 'center')
            y: 'center'             // Vertical Position (Use a number, 'top', 'bottom' or 'center')
        },
        outside: null,              // Use 'x', 'y', or 'xy' to move your jBox outside of the target element
        offset: 0,                  // Offset to final position, you can set different values for x and y with an object e.g. {x: 15, y: 0}

        attributes: {               // Note that attributes can only be 'left' or 'right' when using numbers for position, e.g. {x: 300, y: 20}
            x: 'left',              // Horizontal position, use 'left' or 'right'
            y: 'top'                // Vertical position, use 'top' or 'bottom'
        },
        adjustPosition: false,      // Adjusts the position when there is not enough space (use true, 'flip' or 'move')
        adjustTracker: false,       // By default jBox adjusts the position when opening, to adjust when scrolling or resizing, use 'scroll', 'resize' or 'true' (both events)
        adjustDistance: 5,          // How far from the window edge we start adjusting, use an object to set different values: {bottom: 5, top: 50, left: 5, right: 20}
        fixed: false,               // Your jBox will stay on position when scrolling
        reposition: false,          // Calculates new position when the window-size changes
        repositionOnOpen: true,     // Calculates new position each time jBox opens (rather than only when it opens the first time)
        repositionOnContent: true,  // Calculates new position when the content changes with .setContent() or .setTitle()

        // Pointer
        pointer: false,             // Your pointer will always point towards the target element, so the option outside should be 'x' or 'y'
        pointTo: 'target',          // Setting something else than 'target' will add a pointer even if there is no target element set or found (Use 'top', 'bottom', 'left' or 'right')

        // Animations
        fade: 180,                  // Fade duration in ms, set to 0 or false to disable
        animation: null,            // Animation when opening or closing (use 'pulse', 'zoomIn', 'zoomOut', 'move', 'slide', 'flip', 'tada') (CSS inspired from Daniel Edens Animate.css: http://daneden.me/animate)

        // Appearance
        theme: 'Default',           // Set a jBox theme class
        addClass: '',               // Adds classes to the wrapper
        overlay: false,             // Adds an overlay when jBox opens (set color and opacity with CSS)
        zIndex: 10000,              // Use a high zIndex (your overlay will have the lowest zIndex of all your jBoxes (with overlays) minus one)

        // Delays
        delayOpen: 0,               // Delay opening in ms (Note that the delay will be ignored if your jBox didn't finish closing)
        delayClose: 0,              // Delay closing in ms (Note that there is always a closing delay of at least 10ms to ensure jBox won't be closed when opening right away)

        // Closing events
        closeOnEsc: false,          // Close jBox when pressing [esc] key
        closeOnClick: false,        // Close jBox with mouseclick, use 'true' (click anywhere), 'box' (click on jBox itself), 'overlay' (click on the overlay), 'body' (click anywhere but jBox)
        closeOnMouseleave: false,   // Close jBox when the mouse leaves the jBox area or the area of the attached element
        closeButton: false,         // Adds a close button to your jBox, use 'title', 'overlay', 'box' or true (true will add the button to overlay, title or box, in that order if any of those elements can be found)

        // Other options
        constructOnInit: false,     // Construct jBox when it's being initialized
        blockScroll: false,         // When jBox is open, block scrolling
        appendTo: jQuery('body'),   // Provide an element if you want the jBox to be positioned inside a specific element (only useful for fixed positions or when position values are numbers)
        draggable: null,            // Make your jBox draggable (use 'true', 'title' or provide an element as handle) (inspired from Chris Coyiers CSS-Tricks http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/)
        dragOver: true,             // When you have multiple draggable jBoxes, the one you select will always move over the other ones

        // Events                   // Note: You can use 'this' in the event functions, it refers to your jBox object (e.g. onInit: function() { this.open(); })
        onInit: null,               // Triggered when jBox is initialized
        onBeforeInit: null,         // Triggered when jBox starts initializing, useful to add your own internal functions
        onAttach: null,             // Triggered when jBox attached itself to elements
        // TODO onPosition
        onCreated: null,            // Triggered when jBox is created and is availible in DOM
        onOpen: null,               // Triggered when jBox opens
        onClose: null,              // Triggered when jBox closes
        onCloseComplete: null,      // Triggered when jBox is completely closed (when fading is finished, useful if you want to destroy the jBox when it is closed)

    };
```

Is there a way to filter out only the values that get used ? I.E. the values in the object literal that are actually ever used later in the code and remove the rest from the default object literal.

I created a demo, with the code i extrated **[HERE](http://purplefront.net/tooltip/tooltip.html)**(go to source and open jBox.js) or you can check out the plugin on github too, **[HERE](https://github.com/StephanWagner/jBox/blob/master/Source/jBox.js)**

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic way to do that, but you should start by running your code through http://jshint.com/ and fixing the numerous errors and warnings.

Comment: @TinyGiant Fantastic(bookmarked) !!! i was also looking for tool , that tells me the total number of functions , but i'am afraid this tool does't solve or answer my current question.